# Re-ordering ordered plots after adding annotation in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I just started using ggplot and have gotten pretty far in terms of creating the facets I need. However, the order of the facets gets changed when I add a data frame with annotation for significance.
There are probably too many steps that are causing the reorder so if you have any suggestions to fix the issue and simplify the code, please let me know.

My code is:

```
ggplot(cdata, aes(x= reorder(Speaker_Group, -Overall_Severity), y=Overall_Severity))
geom_bar(aes (fill = Speaker_Group), stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Overall_Severity-se, ymax=Overall_Severity+se), width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9))
facet_grid(Training_Group_f ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free") + scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "darkred", "darkcyan", "black"), labels = c("ALS", "PD", "OA", "YA"))
theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 10),axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 10))
theme(panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"))
geom_signif(data = annotation1_df, aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, annotations = label, y_position = y), textsize = 4, vjust = 1.2, manual = TRUE)
```

If I remove the `geom_signif` call then the order of the facets is accurate (`No_Training, Pre_Training, Post_Training`) but once I add that it re-orders the facets (`No_Training, Post_Training, Pre_Training`). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEvef.png)

`annotation1_df` is given by:

```
annotation1_df <- data.frame(Training_Group_f = c("No_Training", "No_Training", "No_Training", "Pre_Training", "Pre_Training", "Pre_Training", "Post_Training", "Post_Training", "Post_Training"),
  start = c("ALS", "ALS", "ALS", "ALS", "ALS", "ALS", "ALS", "ALS", "ALS"),
  end = c("PD", "OA", "YA", "PD", "OA", "YA", "PD", "OA", "YA"),
  y = c(95, 90, 90, 90, 80, 80, 80, 70, 70),
  label = c("p<.0001", "p<.0001", "p<.0001", "p<.0001", "p<.0001", "p<.0001", "p<.0001", "p<.0001", "p<.0001")
)
annotation1_df
```

I also ordered the levels in `cdata`:

```
cdata$Training_Group_f = factor(cdata$training,levels=c("No_Training","Pre_Training","Post_Training"))
cdata$Speaker_Group_f = factor(cdata$Speaker_Group, levels=c("ALS", "PD", "OA", "YA"))
cdata <- ddply(data, c("speaker", "training"), summarise,
  N = length(overallseverity),
  Overall_Severity = mean(overallseverity),
  sd = sd(overallseverity),
  se = sd / sqrt(N)
)
cdata
```

Answer (score 3):

OP.  As I look through your detailed question, the following note seems quite significant:

> If I remove the `geom_signif` call then the order of the facets is
> accurate (No_Training, Pre_Training, Post_Training) but once I add
> that it re-orders the facets (No_Training, Post_Training,
> Pre_Training).

As you already seem to understand, facet order is determined in one of two ways in `ggplot2`:

- if you are faceting a discrete value and the column is a factor already, the order of the facets will be set according to the order of the levels of that factor.
- if your are faceting a discrete value which is *not* a factor, the column will be converted to a factor and ordering will default to alphanumeric order

So, if your first plot *without* the `geom_signif()` call is accurate, the issue should lie in in that code.  Let's look at that particular line:

```
geom_signif(
  data = annotation1_df,
  aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, annotations = label, y_position = y),
  textsize = 4, vjust = 1.2, manual = TRUE)
```

There's the issue.  Your plot code before references `data = cdata`, and you are faceting on `cdata$Training_Group_f`.  The call to `geom_signif()` references `data = annotation1_df`, which also has `annotation_df$Training_Group_f`.  Plotting both creates a `ggplot` object that is combining a dataset `cdata` (where the levels of the `Training_Group_f` facet are set correctly) and `annotation1_df`, where the levels are apparently not set.

The answer should be to first ensure that the columns for `Training_Group_f` are set as factors with the same levels in *both* datasets, `cdata` and `annotation1_df`.  You'll need to do these two lines and then your facet order should be correct:

```
cdata$Training_Group_f = factor(cdata$training,
    levels=c("No_Training","Pre_Training","Post_Training"))

annotation1_df$Training_Group_f = factor(annotation1_df$training,
    levels=c("No_Training","Pre_Training","Post_Training"))
```

*Note: you may actually see the levels being reversed due to y = 0 being at the bottom left of the plot... I can't remember at this point if that's how facets are positioned, but if so, just reverse the order of the levels for both.*

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read the lengthy description and providing a solution. It worked! The legend is not showing the correct order though (although the colors, values, etc are consistent with the factors/levels), but I figured I can just remove the legend. Thanks again! @chemdork123

Comment: Feel free to post the legend as another question - have a feeling on how to solve that, but if you do, please provide some example data to make a reproducible example (with all info in your question).  Glad I could help.